# PostAsJsonAsync returns 500 Internal Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have been searching solution for few hours and I can't find answer to my problem.
I want to send a post method to a web api and I've tried it first on postman using these json content and it is working.

```
{
"ETickets": [
    {
        "TicketName": "Weekend - Regular Day Pass",
        "TicketAccessType": "PA",
        "TicketGuest": "RDP",
        "IsWeekday": true
    },
    {
        "TicketName": "Weekend - Regular Day Pass",
        "TicketAccessType": "PA",
        "TicketGuest": "RDP",
        "IsWeekday": true
    }
],
"TransactDetails": {
    "CompanyCode": "ONLINE",
    "Surname": "Dela Cruz",
    "FirstName": "Juan",
    "BookingReference": "1113",
    "BookingDate": "2018-08-16T11:31:20:04"
}
```

}

However, when I try it in coding style, I can't make it to work. It says 500 internal server error upon debugging.
Here's the error screenshot:
[image]

Here's my few codes related to my issue:

```
TransactionDetailsViewModel finale = new TransactionDetailsViewModel();
finale.TransacDetails = transacDetail;
finale.ETickets = lsTickets.ToArray();
client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["WebApiAccessToken"].ToString());
HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(url + "api/Transaction/SendTransaction/", finale);
```

And here's the model I'ved used:

```
public class TransactionDetailsViewModel
{
    public TransactionDetails TransacDetails { get; set; }
    public TicketDetailsModel[] ETickets { get; set; }
}

public class TransactionDetails
{
    public string CompanyCode { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string BookingReference { get; set; }
    public DateTime? BookingDate { get; set; }
}

public class TicketDetailsModel
{
    public string TicketAccessType { get; set; }
    public string TicketGuest { get; set; }
    public string TicketName { get; set; }
    public bool IsWeekday { get; set; }
}
```

Do I send the data with the correct format or something to adjust to make it work on sending to a `PostAsJsonAsync`?

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Pleade can you look network tab from your browser for 500 internal Error Details

Comment: Please see my screenshot of error, I've edited my post. Thanks

Comment: image link is broken

Comment: I think the image link is okay, please try to refresh your page, I've tried on different computer and it is not broken.

Comment: already refreshed but I cant see image seing image line  this "However, when I try it in coding style, I can't make it to work. It says 500 internal server error upon debugging. Here's the error screenshot: enter image description here"

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cgIA.jpg   try this link. Thanks

Comment: I already try link to, it can be my network

Comment: What happens when you Serialize your finale variable to JSON? Does it look as you would expect it to look?

Comment: @nvoigt the json adds forward slash on every element not the one I would expect to look when I serialize it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, modify your code just like as

```
var data = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(finale, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

    HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Transaction/SendTransaction/", data);
```

OR You can make request and then send like as

```
HttpResponseMessage response = null;
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url+"/api/Transaction/SendTransaction"))
                {
                    request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["WebApiAccessToken"].ToString());
                    var data = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(finale, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
request.Content = data;
                    response = await client.SendAsync(request);
                }
            }
```

Comment: I'ved tried this code and same problem occurs. 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Can I suggest another process to send request?

Comment: You were using base url in two times. So, how can it work? I was modify my answer. Please check

Comment: I removed the another instance of url but the error still occurs

Comment: Check now and try it

Comment: I think, you have another error. May be it your viewmodel or another

Comment: I double check all the request and data and I saw the error on my viewmodel typo on naming, I tried your code again and now its working! Thanks. I've use your option 2 coding. Thanks again for your help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Please try below line to post data

```
httpClient.PostAsync(url + "/api /Transaction/SendTransaction/", new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(finale).ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
```